# How to return the right type in this extention function

Tags: android, algorithm, kotlin

I know I'm probably doing this wrong but I am a bit stuck on returning the right type in this function.

```
 val dbFields = dbInfo.equipmentList

        fun DbEquipmentWithMediaList.toApiUpdateDeviceList(): ApiUpdateDeviceList {
            val newUpdate: ApiUpdateDeviceList
           newUpdate = dbFields.forEach { ApiUpdateDeviceList(
                    deviceEquipmentId = it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.deviceEquipmentId,
                    secondaryDeviceId = it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.secondaryDeviceId,
                    deviceInstanceId = it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.deviceInstanceId.toString(),
                    deviceSerialNumber = it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.deviceSerialNumber,
                    devicePartNumber = it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.devicePartNumber,
                    deviceManufacturerName = it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.deviceManufacturer,
                    deviceInstallationDate = DateUtil.dateToStringUTCSiteSurvey(it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.deviceInstallationDate),
                    deviceLocation = it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.locationInfo,
                    deviceTechnicianNotes = it.sSEquipmentDbInfo.deviceTechnicianNotes
            )
            }
        }
```

I need to return the function as an ApiUpdateDeviceList after the forEach Loop. Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Here is a more information about the two classes
for the DbEquipmentWithMediaList class and the ApiUpdateDeviceList

For DbEquipmentWithMediaList

```
data class DbEquipmentWithMediaList(
    @Embedded val sSEquipmentDbInfo: SSEquipmentDbInfo,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "media_id",
        entity = SurveySiteDbMedia::class
    )
    val mediaList: List<SurveySiteDbMedia>
)

data class SSEquipmentDbInfo(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "equipment_id", index = true) val equipmentId: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "actual_device_equipmentId") val deviceEquipmentId: Int?,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "secondary_device_id") val secondaryDeviceId: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "secondary_device_checked_status") val secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus: Int?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "device_instance_id") val deviceInstanceId: Int?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "media_names_list") val mediaNames: List<String>? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "device_serial_number") var deviceSerialNumber: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "device_part_number") var devicePartNumber: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "device_manufacturer") var deviceManufacturer: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "device_installation_date") var deviceInstallationDate: Date? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "location") var locationInfo: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "device_technician_notes") var deviceTechnicianNotes: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "image_start_count") val imageStartCount: Int?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "video_start_count") val videoStartCount: Int?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "device_equipment_id") val deviceEquipmentMediaId: Int? = 0,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "device_update_mode") val isDeviceUpdateMode: Boolean
)
```

For the ApiUpdateDeviceList

```
data class ApiUpdateDeviceList(
        @SerializedName("DeviceEquipmentId") val deviceEquipmentId: Int?,
        @SerializedName("DeviceId") val secondaryDeviceId: Int?,
        @SerializedName("DeviceInstance") val deviceInstanceId: String?,
        @SerializedName("SerialNumber") val deviceSerialNumber: String?,
        @SerializedName("PartNumber") val devicePartNumber: String?,
        @SerializedName("ManufacturerName") val deviceManufacturerName: String?,
        @SerializedName("InstallationDate") val deviceInstallationDate: String?,
        @SerializedName("Location") val deviceLocation: String?,
        @SerializedName("TechnicianNotes") val deviceTechnicianNotes: String?
)
```

Comment: Is `DbEquipmentWithMediaList` a class or is it a type alias of some kind of `List`? Same question for `ApiUpdateDeviceList`. You definititely should not be working with some external property and ignoring the receiver of your extension function.

Comment: `DbEquipmentWithMediaList` is a class and `ApiUpdateDeviceList` is a Data Class

Comment: I think we need to see the code of the second class. It’s hard to understand the relation between them. Don’t know if it’s a 1:1 relationship or 1:many from the items of the inner list of your first class.

Comment: I added the two classes that are used in the extended function.

Comment: OK, so it's confusing that the second class has "List" in the name when it only represents one item. It seems you actually need to create a List of these, not a single one, so your return type should be a `List<ApiUpdateDeviceList>`, except with your class renamed to something more suitable. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. But for this instance I still need to return it as `APiUpdateDeviceList`, since it's a type of another field that is a list. Which would be this Field `@SerializedName("UpdateDeviceList") val updateDeviceList: List<ApiUpdateDeviceList> = emptyList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I would rename this class not to have List in it's name, since it represents only one item:

```
ApiUpdateDeviceList -> ApiUpdateDevice
```

And since this is a one-to-many relationship, your return type from this extension function should be `List<ApiUpdateDevice>`.

I would actually first break out the one-to-one relationship into its own extension function, using the `with` scope function to simplify the code:

```
fun SurveySiteDbMedia.toApiUpdateDevice(): ApiUpdateDevice = with(sSEquipmentDbInfo) {
    ApiUpdateDevice(
        deviceEquipmentId = deviceEquipmentId,
        secondaryDeviceId = secondaryDeviceId,
        deviceInstanceId = deviceInstanceId.toString(),
        deviceSerialNumber = deviceSerialNumber,
        devicePartNumber = devicePartNumber,
        deviceManufacturerName = deviceManufacturer,
        deviceInstallationDate = DateUtil.dateToStringUTCSiteSurvey(deviceInstallationDate),
        deviceLocation = locationInfo,
        deviceTechnicianNotes = deviceTechnicianNotes
    )
}
```

You can use the `map` function instead of `forEach` to produce a List of something out of another List. So we use that with the above function to create your list conversion succinctly:

```
fun DbEquipmentWithMediaList.toApiUpdateDeviceList(): List<ApiUpdateDevice> =
    dbFields.map { it.toApiUpdateDevice() }
```

Comment: For what I needed, the first part was correct. But instead of `SurveySiteDbMedia` I used `DbEquipmentEithMediaList` so I can connect to the `sSEquipmentDbInfo`. Then I mapped it on another function and it worked for me. The second function here was not needed. Thank You again.